# $\operatorname{coker}(\phi)$ is discrete for a morphism of Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

suppose $\phi: G \to H$ a morphism of Lie groups such that $d\phi$ is surjective.
Prove that $\operatorname{coker}\phi$ is discrete.

My attempts:

- Prove that $\phi(G)$ is open which will lead to $H/\phi(G)$ is discrete: we have no topological information to use here.
- prove that $Lie(H/\phi(G))=0$.

I don't know how to proceed and I don't see how to use the surjectivity of $d\phi$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you say you have no topological information to use here? You know that $\phi$ is a submersion. Submersions are locally projections, and are thus [open maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607049/90543).

Comment: Thank you! this is useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the kernel of $\phi$, $G/N$ is a Lie group and there exists a Lie hmomorphism $f:G/N\rightarrow H$, the differential of $f$ at any point of $G/N$ is an isomorphism, the local inverse mapping theorem implies that $f$ is open.

Comment: Thank you @Aristide. Why is $d\phi$ a local isomorphism? it is surjective but is it injective?

Comment: $f$ the quotient map $G/N\rightarrow H$ is a local isomorphism.