# I want to show that this set is open in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces

I don't think this is meant to be hard. I came up with this set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in order to address this bigger problem I am doing. I took the helicoid and thickened it in the direction of a transversal vector at each point:
If $f(r, \theta) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, \theta)$ where $(r, \theta) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then I define this set $U := \{f(r, \theta) + q(\sin \theta, -\cos \theta, r) | q \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\}$. I want to show $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$! I'm having a stupid moment, could someone please help?

Comment: I mistook helicoid for a helix in a now deleted comment. Sorry about not checking the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$f_r=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0),\qquad f_\theta=(-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,1)\ ,\qquad
f_r\times f_\theta=(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta, r)$$
(note the $r$ at the end of the line!). The unit normal is therefore given by
$$n(r,\theta)={1\over\sqrt{1+r^2}}(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta, r)\ .$$
A helicoidal shell of thickness $2\epsilon$ is then produced by
$$\Psi:\quad(r,\theta,t)\mapsto f(r,\theta)+ t\,n(r,\theta)\qquad\bigl(r\in{\mathbb R},\  \theta\in{\mathbb R},\  -\epsilon<t<\epsilon\bigr)\ .$$
In order to show that this shell is an open set in ${\mathbb R}^3$ you have to verify that the Jacobian $J_\Psi(r,\theta, t)$ is $\ne0$ at all parameter points $(r,\theta,t)$ with $|t|$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Why would the Jacobian being nonzero mean that the shell is open, sorry?

Comment: @ActonGrey inverse function theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263837/smooth-map-with-surjective-jacobian-is-open

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you so much!

Comment: @Christian Blatter typos: the third component of $f_\theta$ should read $1$, not $r$; and "open set in $\mathbb{R}$" should read "open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$"

Comment: and @Acton uses a shell produced by $t\sqrt{1+r^2}n(r,\theta)$, not $tn(r,\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this set is a 2D surface, so it's probably not open in $R^3$...